# Has anyone yet figured out how sensory signals for eyes and ears are encoded by our organ into electrical signals?

Tags: sensor

The most obvious way to give sight to blind and hearing to deaf is to give them a replacement organ for these. In order to do that we would need to understand how our eyes and ears encode sensory information into electrical signals which then go into the brain. My question is, how close are to understand this mechanism at this time?

Comment: This is more of a question for biology, or bio-chemistry. If our brains were made of transistors and IC's, then we could help. I can say the retina pre-decodes what we see into 12 patterns before sending them to the brain. To answer these questions properly would take several books.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about biology/physiology not EE.

Comment: Although there is electrical activity associated with neurons, the "signal" that the brain receives is biochemical, not electrical. I have done some work with retinal implants, but the goal there is to replace only the photoreceptors (the only cells affected by certain types of eye disease), and allow the existing upper layers of the retinal do the "encoding".

Comment: The big problem with a "replacement organ" is the number of channels involved in the signal path, the eye is probably around 10-100megapixels, How could you possibly squeeze that many wires into something.
The ear is not so bad,  Older hearing implants were 12channel, Cochlear is 22ch (and releasing a 120ch device). Whether you could integrate that technology into bio-compatible hearing module, and power it from available biological energy sources is something I would guess as "not impossible" in the next 20 yrs.

Comment: They have yet to emulate sensors to interface the same parallel channels per frequency or pixel and even replicate without power in the required size

Answer (score 2):

It's really a biochemistry problem, the neurone signal path is just a string of electrical pulses, the larger the signal the faster the pulses, typically at several kHz.

The basic encoder analogue would be a relaxation oscillator, consider:

1. a **capacitor** ,
2. that is charged with a **current** proportional to the signal , a photodiode would do that ,
3. when the capacitor reaches a **trigger** voltage it triggers a SCR like device like a DIAC for example to discharge the capacitor into the signal line, sending a pulse down it.
4. the capacitor starts charging again and cycle repeats.
   So effectively it is a current to frequency convertor.

The eye organ has good quantum efficiency, the black and white low light sensors (rods) would generate one pulse per two photons. The color sensor are about tens time less sensitive, but are much smaller, hence get better resolution. There are a variety of other mechanisms that roll back the sensivity as signal increases to produce a logarithmic type response.